# Why do I see the wide spacing in my bibliography in Latex?

Tags: latex, biblatex

What package in latex can I use to close the big gaps in the bibliography as shown in the attached picture?

[image: present output]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, urls only break at very specific points, like `/`. If you want to enable more possible break points, you can add

```
\usepackage{xurl}
```

to your preamble.